# Give a new amount of something when greater than a defined amount

Tags: php

Okay so I am trying to award jackpot entries every time a user completes a task, but I want to give out more than one entry when the task awards more than a certain amount.

Let me break this down.

When a user completes a task that awards $0.05 or more they receive 1 entry into the jackpot. What I am trying to achieve is this. When they complete a task that is worth $0.50 they receive an additional 1 entry and then for every $0.25 more they get another 1 so if they complete a task worth $1.00 they should get a total of 4 entries. 1 for the initial $0.05, 1 for the task being worth $0.50, 1 for reaching $0.75, and 1 more for reaching $1.00

I am not sure how to go about doing this. So all I have when it comes to updating in the database is this.

```
if($offprate >= $rafminp || $offcrate >= $rafminc){
$stmt=$db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET jackpot_e=jackpot_e+'1' WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

which is just for the initial $0.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I thinking too simple?

```
$amount = 0.5;
$credits = 0;
switch($amount) {
  case 0.05: $credits = 1; break;
  case 0.50: $credits = 2; break;
  case 0.75: $credits = 3; break;
  case 1.00: $credits = 4; break;
}
$stmt=$db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET jackpot_e=jackpot_e+'$credits' WHERE username = ?");
```

Or maybe even:

```
$all_amounts = array(0.05, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00);
$credits = array_search($amount, $all_amounts)+1; # returns -1 when not found
```

If you don't have exact values, replace the switch statement with an if-else cascade.

---

Re-reading your question, it seems that the amount has no upper bound. In that case:

```
$credits = 0;
if($amount == 0.05)
  $credits = 1;
if($amount >= 0.50) 
  $credits = floor(2+($amount-0.50)/0.25);
```

Comment: You might want to check your assertion `# no need for break;, there can only be one match`